# Can't get result with date

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i am creating Api to get my store quantity according store id and date from to but i had no result code below
please can any one help me in this issue.

---

```
public class StoresQtyDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemLookupCode { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string itemDescription { get; set; }
    public string SubDescription3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? SnapShotPrice { get; set; }
    public double? SnapShotQuantity { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public DateTime lastupdated { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public interface IStoresQtyRepository
{
    Task<StoresQty[]> GetItemsByDate(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, int storeId);

}
```

---

```
public class StoresQtyRepository : IStoresQtyRepository
{
    private readonly ApiSiteDbContext _db;
    private readonly ILogger<StoresQtyRepository> _logger;
    public StoresQtyRepository(ApiSiteDbContext db, ILogger<StoresQtyRepository> logger)
    {
        _db = db;
        _logger = logger;
    }

  public async Task<StoresQty[]> GetItemsByDate(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, int storeId)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Getting Allt Stores Items with Store ID {storeId} from Date {fromDate} to date {toDate}");
        var query = _db.storesQties.Where(s => s.lastupdated == fromDate && toDate == DateTime.Now && s.StoreId == storeId);
        return await query.ToArrayAsync();
    }
```

*******************Controller

```
    private readonly IStoresQtyRepository _storesQty;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public StoresQtiesController(IStoresQtyRepository storesQty, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _storesQty = storesQty;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
   
}


    [HttpGet("StoresQties")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<StoresQtyDto[]>> GetItemsByDate(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, int storeId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var results = await _storesQty.GetItemsByDate(fromDate, toDate, storeId);
                if (!results.Any())
                    return NotFound($"No Items found in store with id {storeId} and date from {fromDate}");

                var mappedEntities = _mapper.Map<StoresQtyDto[]>(results);
                return Ok(mappedEntities);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Database Failure");
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

---

after i run it in Postman its return not found , but date and storeId already exist in data base

Comment: How do you pass the DateTime type and where is '_mapper' referenced from? Whether you use automapper? Because I tested your code and inserted data in the local database, it returns the required data correctly except _mapper.

Comment: @karney private readonly IStoresQtyRepository _storesQty;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public StoresQtiesController(IStoresQtyRepository storesQty, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _storesQty = storesQty;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

Comment: i must to enter time with date in url variable to return data

Comment: Please check if 'StoresQtyRepository' is injected into ConfigureServices. services.AddScoped<IStoresQtyRepository,StoresQtyRepository>();   If it does not work, please provide the detailde error in the debugging process and the implementation of automapper. Because I can return data successfunlly.